# MongoDB DeleteMany not deleting documents

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

So, when i run this query to delete some friend request documents:

```
    db.friendRequests.deleteMany([
      {
        $and: [
          { author: ObjectId("636a88de3e45346191cf4257") },
          { friend_id: ObjectId("636faabb1861c5b8773f751e") },
        ],
      },
    ]);
```

then it doesn't delete anything, and i dont know why.

**Heres the friendRequests document exported as JSON from MongoDB Compass:**

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63764d512bf0d70cbce32664"
  },
  "author": {
    "$oid": "636fa1ce289c56d125ac8a4a"
  },
  "friend_id": {
    "$oid": "636a88de3e45346191cf4257"
  },
  "request_at": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1668697425541"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63764d622bf0d70cbce32673"
  },
  "author": {
    "$oid": "636cf37d8a8b51a38932d3d8"
  },
  "friend_id": {
    "$oid": "636a88de3e45346191cf4257"
  },
  "request_at": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1668697442809"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "637cc8e760709f87c46ad5a9"
  },
  "author": {
    "$oid": "636a88de3e45346191cf4257"
  },
  "friend_id": {
    "$oid": "636faabb1861c5b8773f751e"
  },
  "request_at": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1669122279674"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
}]
```

Can you help me why it doesn't delete anything? Thanks!

Comment: What values did you supplied for `author` and `friend_id`?

Comment: oh sorry i didn't changed that, i will update the question

Comment: Are you sure it is correct to wrap your `$and` criteria with []? You may want to use a syntax like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pkYe348fxdj). Just replace the `find` with `deleteMany`

Comment: It says: { acknowledged: true, deletedCount: 0 }

Comment: It could be something wrong with your `db`. Please check which db it is pointing to. It may not be the one that `friendRequests` is residing in.

Comment: Oh xd. Its working in the compass but not in nestjs mongoose

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I just had to put a `.exec()` after the deleteMany query